# How to group by a part of string?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this data in MongoDB.

```
{ _id: "abc*hello*today*123", "value": 123 },
{ _id: "abc*hello*today*999", "value": 999 },
{ _id: "xyz*hello*tomorrow*123", "value": 123 }
```

What I want is to group by the first part before "*{number}". This is what I want to achieve:

```
{
    _id: "abc*hello*today",
    results: [
        { _id: "abc*hello*today*123", "value": 123 },
        { _id: "abc*hello*today*999", "value": 999 }
    ]
},
{
    _id: "xyz*hello*tomorrow",
    results: [
        { _id: "xyz*hello*tomorrow*123", "value": 123 }
    ]
}
```

I tried this:

```
{
  $group:{
      "_id":"$_id".slice(0, -4)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with regex as below:

```
.*(?=\*\d+)
```

The above regex will match and retrieve the value before the * and numbers.

[Demo @ Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/ToV58h/1)

---

1. `$set` - Set `firstPart` field.

   1.1. `$getField` - Get the `match` value from the object *1.1.1*.

   1.1.1. `$regexFind` - Match the `_id` with regex.
2. `$group` - Group by `firstPart`.
3. `$unset` - Remove the `results.firstPart` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      firstPart: {
        $getField: {
          field: "match",
          input: {
            $regexFind: {
              input: "$_id",
              regex: ".*(?=\\*\\d+)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$firstPart",
      results: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "results.firstPart"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IhDLrVAVVKR)

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution:** If your `_id` has always the same format `(field1*field2*field3*numbers)`, you can use `$split` + `$slice` + `$reduce` operators

##### Explanation:

```
$split('field1*field2*field3*numbers', '*')                   -> ['field1', 'field2', 'field3','number']
$slice(['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], 2)                        -> ['item1', 'item2']
$reduce(['field1', 'field2', 'field3'], 'Concatenate with *') -> 'field1*field2*field3'
```

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $slice: [
          { $split: [ "$_id", "*"] },
          3
        ]
      },
      results: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$_id",
          initialValue: "",
          in: { $concat: [ "$$value", "*", "$$this" ] }
        }
      },
      results: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G3HbmewVdqY)